# Performance Impact using MPI on a single machine

Tags: performance, mpi

Is there a significant performance impact using MPI on an N-core single machine compared to using N machines with 1-core (on hpc nodes)?

I am running WRF (mesoscale weather modeling) using MPI on single machine AMD Ryzen 64-core, and for some reason performance is lower than I expected. It is weird, because I would assume that running on the same machine all communications among ranks would be much faster than on nodes, and so overall performance better.
thanks

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly appropriate to use MPI on a multi-core, single machine.  If performance is "lower than you expect"... you need to look elsewhere to determine why.  One good place to start is Perfmon (if you happen to be using Windows) to ensure your cores are actually being utilized.

Comment: Thank you, this is a perfect valid answer. How can I label it as answered from the comment?

Comment: you need to characterize your app! FWIW, most apps are memory bound, which means you need more sockets (e.g. more memory bandwidth) in order to improve the performance. But only a few apps (such as linpack) are CPU bound, which means adding more cores (e.g. more flops) can be enough to improve performance. Last but not least, beware of Amdahl's law (scalability is limited by the serial part of your app).

Comment: What does "lower than expected" means? As pointed out by Gilles, a single CPU socket doesn't provide the memory bandwidth you get when running on multiple CPU sockets, so anything that doesn't fit in the CPU cache is going to be slower on a single node with the same number of MPI ranks. This is not an MPI problem. It is just basic performance engineering.

Comment: Thanks. So you mean that if the communication between nodes is intensive (not the RAM usage) a single CPU socket may produce a bottle neck in performance. Interesting, now I just wonder if there is an easy way to check if that may be happening in my case.

Comment: And as @GillesGouaillardet points out, most apps are memory bound so in general, the conclusion would be that using MPI in a single machine is not good a idea right? (independently if that is what is happening in my case)

Comment: The conclusions are you need to characterize your application instead of making any assumptions in order to have reasonable expectations w.r.t. the benefits of naive parallelization (regardless your programming model) within a NUMA domain (a single machine might have more than one socket and/or NUMA domain). FWIW the STREAM benchmark is textbook memory bound, but you would generally use multiple threads in order to get the maximum memory bandwidth of a given NUMA domain.

Comment: yes, I understand there are may reasons that may affect performance and should be taken into account. But for people who are not experts like me, is usually good to have a rule of thumb. To know what is common and what is not. I am a bit confused now about the whole thing.... Anyway, thanks for the explanation.